# Database design: how to effectively manage about 4000 databases with mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

It sounds crazy, but i started a data intensive project[collecting online store inventories] which later grew to be very big. I currently have about 2000 users and each user has about 100 tables. So in essence, i created the system so that each user had his own mysql database and hosted it on a dedicated server. The problem is, the server becomes very slow and breaks due to the pressure and connections. Is there a tool i can use to optimize the db? or i should redesign to only 1 database, which will mean redesigning the whole system? I need an advice and help

Comment: Look at the connection settings of every server. It should handle 2000 users. Are the 2000 users using it simultaneously?

Comment: Also we can't give you any meaningful advice without knowing what are you trying to do:)

Comment: @Peter Minchev: what about that? where do I see it on mysql server?

Comment: Does it break due to connections, or due to the fact that your queries run forever because you have 200000 tables?

Comment: Look here - http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum112/456.htm.

Comment: @Naltharial: my hosting agents told me the no of databases are many for the cpanel and the cpu of the server.

Comment: @PetarMinchev: thanks man. Its a project of collecting data files of clients and saving them to a db

Comment: 4000 databases are obviously about 3999 too many in respect to how many the usual application needs. I'd go with "redesign", because sooner or later it's going to scale out of control.
In the mean time, you could try optimizing your queries to see if you can save on precious CPU cycles.

Comment: @karto - Consider using a fileserver. A database is not a place for saving a large amount of files.

Comment: @PetarMinchev, the default setting for MySQL is 151 simultanious connections.

Comment: @PetarMinchev: I can redesign the database to about 15. Then it means, for my 4000 users, they will be connecting/reconnecting to 15 databases. so that makes 4000*15 connections, thats if they are all logged in. Whiles if i maintain 4000 dbs it will be 4000*1 connections. any sense in what i'm saying??

Comment: @karto, Do all these DBs reside on the same physical box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4000 databases for **one** system?! Wowzer, did you invent Google?

I'd definitely say that you need to redesign that setup - unless your 'system' is actually database hosting and each user has paid for a private db, of course.

Nothing wrong with having multiple discrete databases, but 2-per-user is the wrong approach.

The 'right' approach will depend entirely on what your system is meant to do.

You mention everyone has a dedicated server too - this should prevent contention issues for other users. Are you sure it's not *shared* hosting?

Comment: I have a dedicated server [2GB RAM]. and on this server i have these databases.

Comment: @karto: ok, there's the problem - 4,000 databases on a server with 2GB RAM will be slow, regardless of design. My laptop had 2GB in it and that struggled to run a dev instance of SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks widor: Do i increase the RAM then to about 16GB? whiles i try to redesign?

Comment: RAM is cheap and it would certainly help the connections/contention issue but the real issue here is the design of the database(s) - you may still need many, or perhaps you can refactor the setup into one or two. Throwing more RAM at it is only a temporary solution.

Comment: :I can redesign the database to about 15. Then it means, for my 4000 users, they will be connecting/reconnecting to 15 databases. so that makes 4000*15 connections, thats if they are all logged in. Whiles if i maintain 4000 dbs it will be 4000*1 connections. any sense in what i'm saying??

Comment: I thought it was 2,000 users and 4,000 dbs? Anyway, if what you're saying is true - and they all have to hit 15 dbs each, in that specific case then yes you'd end up with 15x the number of db connections

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3899/discussion-between-karto-and-widor)

Answer (score 1):

Nine times out of ten, when someone structures an application database this way (segmenting identical data into different databases, or even into different tables) it's a mistake based on an unnecessary attempt to pre-optimize the system.

But without more information we cannot tell whether:

1. This is one one of the nine times it's a mistake, or the tenth time, when it's an appropriate design.
2. Whether the number of connections is what's causing the performance problems you see (which would be solved by switching to a single database) or something else.

Comment: :Its about collecting distinc data for users and storing them. The data collected is intensive in volume.

Comment: I can redesign the database to about 15. Then it means, for my 4000 users, they will be connecting/reconnecting to 15 databases. so that makes 4000*15 connections, thats if they are all logged in. Whiles if i maintain 4000 dbs it will be 4000*1 connections. any sense in what i'm saying??